# Fractional calculus reference for hypercyclicity of fractional derivative.

Tags: reference-request, semigroup-of-operators, fractional-calculus

Two years ago in graduate school I came across an article that gave a gentle introduction to the fractional derivative $D^\alpha$ and derived some properties of the semigroup $(D^\alpha)_{\alpha\geq 0}$,  including the hypercyclicity of the semigroup.

I don't remember much more than that, especially the lingo that the article used.  I wish I would have saved it, but after many hours surfing the web, I thought I'd reach out to see if anyone has references to fractional derivatives,  hypercyclicity, and things of that ilk.

Comment: Actually there are *many* ways for defining fractional derivatives (via the Fourier or Laplace transform, à-la-Cauchy, à-la-Grunwald-Letnikov etc) so it might be useful to know which definition was given.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Unfortunately, I don't remember much about the document at all.